# What would be the reason for not exporting context object directly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Recently I see many people export a function that already used `useContext` like this:

```js
const WindowSizeContext = React.createContext({})

function useWindowSizeContext () {
  return useContext(WindowSizeContext)
}

export {
  useWindowSizeContext
}
```

Instead of exporting the context directly:

```js
const WindowSizeContext = React.createContext({})

export {
  WindowSizeContext
}
```

What would be the purpose for this? Is it used to prevent the context object from being misused?

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, if you wrap the context inside another funtion which uses the useContext, then you have to import only that wrapper function. On the other hand if you export context object directly you will have to import both the context object and the useContext.  Other than that I can't think of any other benifit.

Comment: Yes I cannot think of another benefit as well. Thats why I am asking.